# Working backwards from Python namespace to package

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working from someone else's code, and they're using openCV, therefore they used "import cv2". I didn't have it installed in my environment at the time so I needed to install that module. Having moved from MATLAB I'm still remembering different packages, but I remembered cv2 is openCV. However, had I not known cv2 was openCV, is there a programmatic way I can find out the package name from the import? i.e: using cv2, and not having openCV installed, finding out what cv2 is?

Comment: Familiar problem. I think that the majority of packages I know have identical import name and package name. There are a few really confusing ones for which the import name is actually the name of a different package. So if you want to install all dependencies at once (and the project lacks a requirements.txt file, which is a mistake) you can filter out the import statements, install manually the ones that are different from their respective package names and install automatically the rest (and then create a requirements.txt file).

Comment: Usually after ```import <module_name>```, ```<module_name>.__doc__ ``` should say something about module. Sometimes, developers may not remember to update it.